# Infinite sum involving $\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{2^{2n}}$ resulting in gamma function product

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, binomial-coefficients, gamma-function

I enjoy sums featuring $$\rm{T}(n) = \frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{2^{2n}} = (-1)^n \binom{1/2}{n},$$ and I'm on the lookout for techniques of handling sums of these quantities.

For a couple examples,  MSE [2797610](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2797610/proof-of-identity-sum-limits-k-0n-binomnk-binom2kk-frac-1k2) and MSE [2797729](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2797729/taylor-expansion-of-ln1-sqrt1-x) have helped show me a couple ways to handle such sums, such as manipulating generating functions.

---

My question here is: How can I show that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \rm{T}(2n)\rm{T}(n)^2 = \frac{\pi}{\big(\Gamma(\frac{5}{8})\Gamma(\frac{7}{8})\big)^2  } ?$$

Such a sum arose when I attempted to evaluate the integral $$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dx dy}{\sqrt{2-\cos(x)-\cos(y)}},$$ and was evaluated using Mathematica.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1$

Comment: Observation: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty T(2n) T(n)^2 = {}_3F_2\left(\frac14,\frac24,\frac34;1,1;1\right),$$ where $${}_3F_2$$ is the [generalized hypergeometric function](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/)

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is some known identity which allows you to reduce this to $$\frac{\pi}{\big(\Gamma(\frac{5}{8})\Gamma(\frac{7}{8})\big)^2  } $$

Comment: For example see here: http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/03/02/01/

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch  Good thinking. If you write up your comments as an answer, I'll accept it. I don't have much background with hypergeometric identities, so I'd appreciate a link with a little more discussion in your answer.